# Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1 on sitecore upgrade to 9.2

Tags: sitecore9, solr7

I am trying to update sitecore from 9.0.2 to 9.2

I have installed a new instance of 7.5

Currently my sitecore site is using solr 6.6.2.

I have changed the solr.search connection string to new 7.5 solr instance.

But when I tried to load the site it is showing below error

Server Error in '/' Application.
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting and restoring you license.xml file, this worked for me.